# Puppet: err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Tags: passenger, puppet

I install puppet 2.6.18, test it and it was working  okay.

Then I install Apache and Passenger on the Puppet server.

I run on a puppet agent:

puppet agent —test

And I got the error:

"warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
   err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run"

In the puppet server access_log I have:

"GET /production/catalog/puppet.agent.domain?facts=eNqVV2… &facts_format=b64_zlib_yaml HTTP/1.1" 404 343 "-" "-"

And in the error_log I have:

File does not exist: /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd/public/production

I check the file /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd/public  - is empty.

I just create it as part of the installation.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem **solved**.

On the puppet server:

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
stop and start httpd.
```

Thanks.